# Python - drawing a flower with turtle by recursive function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a turtle-graphics flower with `num` petals. However, when I run my code I only get one single petal printed out. The error I get is under the `def flower(num, i = 1)` part of the code, but I am not sure how I can fix it.

```
import time
from turtle import *

pensize(2)
pencolor("orange")
bgcolor("green")
fillcolor("blue")
hideturtle()

def halfPetal():
    forward(50)
    left(30)
    forward(75)
    left(30)
    forward(50)
    left(120)

def petal():
    for i in range(2):
        halfPetal()

def flower(num, i=1):
    if i==1:
        begin_fill()
        for i in range(num):
            petal()
            left(360/petal())
        end_fill()

flower(12)
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  This generally includes the full error message.

Comment: @Prune im pretty sure there is no error ... it just does not draw the image OP expcted... he did not do a good job of describing his expected output

Comment: @JoranBeasley: the posted code faults with the error I cited.  Also, note that OP says "The error I get ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least *one* problem is at the line:

```
        left(360/petal())
```

`petal` does not return a value, so you're trying to divide by `None`.  There is no such operation in Python, so you get a fatal error.  Instead, I think you need to divide by the quantity of petals you're going to draw:

```
        left(360.0 / num)
```